# TreeMap is sorted in an unusual way

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying to print a list of words and their occurrences in a table, sorted by occurrences. I somehow ended up with using TreeMap + StreamAPI to sort the thing, problem is that my sort order is scuffed. It currently looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vliep.png)

For some reason, despite me trying to sort by keys first and by occurrence second to make the final Map sorted by Occurrence, number keys are still prioritized when sorting.

Here is my code:

```java
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/application")
public class ApplicationController {

    @GetMapping
    public List<String> fileSelection() {

        List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();

        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("placeholder.txt");
        File dir = null;

        try {

            dir = new File(url.toURI()).getParentFile();

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        for (File f : dir.listFiles(path -> path.getName().contains(".txt"))) {

            if (!f.getName().equals("placeholder.txt")) {

                files.add(f.getName());

            }

        }

        return files;

    }

    @GetMapping("/{file}/lines")
    public Map<String, Integer> processFile(@PathVariable("file") String fileName) {

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Integer> stringMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        try {

            lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "src", "main", "resources", fileName));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        String string = String.join(" ", lines);
        String[] arr = string.split(" ");

        for (String s : arr) {

            if (stringMap.containsKey(s)) {

                stringMap.put(s, stringMap.get(s) + 1);

            } else {

                stringMap.put(s, 1);

            }

        }

        TreeMap<String, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(stringMap);

        Map<String, Integer> resultMap =
                sortedMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                                (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));

        return resultMap;

    }

}
```

In case something is wrong at the FrontEnd:

```js
window.onload = () => {

    getFiles()

}

function getFiles() {

    fetch(`/application`, {

        method: 'GET'

    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => document.getElementById("fileList").innerHTML = data.map(filename =>
            `<option value="${filename}">${filename}</option>`).join(''));

}

function readLines() {

    let file = document.getElementById("fileList").value;

    fetch(`/application/${file}/lines`, {

        method: 'GET'

    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {

            console.log(data)

            var keys = Object.keys(data)

                let html = `<tr><th>Word</th><th>Occurrence</th></tr>`;

                keys.forEach(key => {

                    if (key.substring(0, 1) !== "1") {
                        html += `<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${data[key]}</td></tr>`
                    }else{
                        html += `<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${data[key]}</td></tr>`
                    }

                })


                document.getElementById("showTable").innerHTML = html;

        });

}
```

Comment: Where is the connection to javascript?

Comment: Forgot to add some JS code for the frontEnd, will edit.

Comment: Have you tried calling your endpoint by hand? That way you can find out, if the problem is on the frontend or on the backend side.

Comment: When I manually call the endpoint, the map is perfectly sorted by occurence, meaning "the" with 35000 entries is first.

Comment: "by keys first and by occurrence second" doesn't make sense regarding your question and code, it is not possible to have more than one entry for each word (In general a map key is unique anyway). So assuming you want to sort the map by the values descending order, your code is correct:
```